# linux script: mass rename of files with whitespaces

Tags: linux, shell, file-io, whitespace

I wrote a script to rename several files at once and adding leading zeros.
the script takes as first parameter the files to be renamed, the second is the new name and as a third you can give a new extension

it actually works as long as the files do not contain whitespaces (test asd 1.txt / test asd 2.txt) because then the output is:

```
~/Desktop $ gpRenameWithZero test\ asd\* test_ mp3
ls: cannot access test: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access asd*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access test: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access asd*: No such file or directory
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#rename a group of files with adding padding zero: gpRenameWithZero $1=filesToBeRenamed $2=newName $3=filetype: gpRenameWithZero \* newName_ jpg

#123 files -> length of number are 3 digits
numberOfDigits=$(ls $1| wc -l | xargs expr length)

#take extension from command line or take from filename
if [ $# -gt 2 ]; then
    extension=$3
else
    extension=$(ls -rt $1 | head -n 1 | rev | cut -d . -f1 | rev)
fi

#Preview
ls -rt $1 | cat -n | while read n f; do echo mv "$f" `printf "$2%0$numberOfDigits"d".$extension" $n`; done

read -p "Do you wish to rename [y/n]?" yn
case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) ls -rt $1 | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" `printf "$2%0$numberOfDigits"d".$extension" $n`; done;;
    [Nn]* ) ;;
esac
```

I already tried with quoting / double-quoting the vriables and the parameters, escaping / not escaping.

How to fix this case? or is there an easier script, which takes files to be renamed, newnames and extension as parametes) to rename multiple files.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: why don't you use the `rename` utility? For instance I sometimes use `rename "s/ /_/g" *` to remove spaces in my filenames

Answer (score 0):

You get yourself the idea, why is true, what the comments said: Don't parse output from `ls`.

In such cases, you need deal with NULL-terminated filenames. Here are many commands what can use such NULL-terminaled strings.

The `find` command could output NULL-terminated filenames, using arg `-print0` or with exactly specified `-print "<format>\0"`.

Because you want sort (number) files by it's modification time (`ls -rt`), you need to use some tricks. So

- the `find` command (the GNU version) could print out the file modification time
- need sort them by this time
- and after cutting of the time field, you will have an sorted list of filenames

This can be achieved for example with the next commands:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "*" -printf "%T@:%p\0" |sort -zrn |sed -z 's/[^:]*://'
                                                  ^^^^^^^^         ^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^ 
modification-time-in-seconds<colon>path-name<NULL>---+              |                |
            sort the NULL-terminated lines numerically (by time) ---+                |
               remove the <time><colon> part, so only the filename remains ----------+
```

You can put the above into an bash function for easier use, like:

```
sort_files_by_time() {
        find "${1:-.}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${2:-*}" -printf "%T@:%p\0" | sort -zrn | sed -z 's/[^:]*://'
}
```

The above function could take two optional parameters:

1. directory name for the find (default:.)
2. pattern for filaname search (default:*)

Now you have a NULL-terminates list of sorted filenames by time, and need read and use them. The next loop

```
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r path ; do
    dir=$(dirname "$path")
    file=$(basename "$path")

    #do what you want

done < <(sort_files_by_time)
```

*ALWAYS* double quote "$variables" what could contain spaces.

Comment: i noticed that when i replace whitespaces in the $1 with \\* it works:"gpRenameWithZero test\ asd\\* test_ mp3" becomes "gpRenameWithZero test\\*asd\\* test_ mp3". Just a workaround but i dont have to change my script :)

Answer (score 0):

In Unix, wildcard expansion of command line arguments is performed by the shell - before being passed to the program.

This script will not work even if there were no spaces in the filenames. For example, if there were three files *song1.mp3*, *song_2.MP3* and *song_0003.mpeg3*, running `gpRenameWithZero song* test_ mp3` the script will be passed five arguments: $1 will be "song1.mp3", $2 will be "song_0003.mpeg3", $3 will be "song_2.MP3", $4 will be "test_" and $5 will be "mp3". So the $1 in your script is not what you expect.

You are much better off treating the new file name prefix and the extension as the first and second arguments, and then the remaining arguments (no matter how many there are) will be the file names. A more advanced solution could even parse them as separate options, so that all the arguments are the filenames (i.e. the first and second arguments are not treated differently).

```
#!/bin/sh
# Usage: renameFiles prefix extension {filenames}

# First argument is the new file name prefix

PREFIX=$1
shift

# Second argument is the new file name extension

EXT=$1
shift

# Calculate the maximum width of the number in the new file names

TMP=`echo $# | wc -c`
NUMBER_OF_DIGITS=`expr $TMP - 1`  # Because TMP also counts the newline character

# Process all the remaining arguments as file names

COUNT=1
for FILE in "$@"
do
  NEW_NAME=`printf "${PREFIX}%0${NUMBER_OF_DIGITS}d.${EXT}" $COUNT`

  # If you wish, prompt the user here

  mv "$FILE" "$NEW_NAME"
  COUNT=`expr $COUNT + 1`
done

#EOF
```

The double quotes around the $@ and the first argument to the *mv* command are needed for the script to work if any of the arguments file names contains whitespace. The double quotes around the second argument to the *mv* command is needed for the script to work if the prefix and/or extension contains whitespace.

Comment: i know that "gpRenameWithZero song* test_ mp3" would no work. But with espacing * it works: "gpRenameWithZero song\\* test_ mp3". It also works when you replace whitespaces in the parameter with \\*

Comment: You are correct: if the wildcard is escaped, then it is not expanded when first passed into the script, but expanded once $1 is substituted and then expanded inside the script. Still, not a good approach because deliberately passing in escaped wildcards is not conventional and not necessary.